# How to play youtube video without UIWebView or detect video player when youtube video start playing using webview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube, video-streaming, overlay

I need to play youtube video in my iOS application and while video is playing I need to add an overlay on video.

1.Now how can i run youtube video in native player?

2.if I play video in UIWebview then how can i detect that video is
 playing and how to add overlay on the video?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MPMoviePlayerViewController` cannot directly play youtube video urls.You need to extract the url before loading `MPMoviePlayerViewController` with the url.

you can see a working demo in my github repo:

Try this::
 https://github.com/DpzAtMicRO/IOSYoutubePlayer

`LBYoutubeExtractor` extracts the youtube Url with JSON.
                  Please do read the README.md before you use this in your application.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

MPMoviePlayerViewController is a good one but last commit is years ago. I found another solution called 'XCDYouTubeKit' which supports iPhone/iPad and iOS7 onwards with full screen YouTube video.

You can access github page at [here](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) and fully documented tutorial at [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/XCDYouTubeKit/2.5.2/)

This is what official developer says in his page:

> The only official way of playing a YouTube video inside an app is with a web view and the iframe player API. Unfortunately, this is very slow and quite ugly, so I wrote this player to give users a better viewing experience.