# how to play private channel video of youtube in iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, video, youtube, private

I want to play private video in my app, requirement is: User should able to play private video without asking user name and password. I have user name and password. I can hard code and show to client. I want to know how to do this? Please help me. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: may be this link help you:

Comment: may be this thread help you:   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029859/iphone-app-how-to-play-youtube-video-in-app-using-mpmovieplayercontroller

Comment: check my answer here, it works
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702306/how-to-play-youtube-video-without-uiwebview-or-detect-video-player-when-youtube/13702467#13702467